# read pictures on a local http path

Tags: python, http, path

I want to open a picture that is an output of another program as `http://192.168.1.100:8123/pic/2021-03-31/snap/238371315.jpg`

the code I'm having trouble with:

```
def get_pic(data):
    img_path='http://192.168.1.100:8123/pic/2021-03-31/snap/238371315.jpg'
    pic={'image': open(img_path, mode='rb')}
    return pic
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\linebot-client\client_script.py", line 144, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\linebot-client\client_script.py", line 134, in main
    final_pic =get_pic(data1)
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\linebot-client\client_script.py", line 107, in get_pic
    pic={'image': open(img_path, mode='rb')}
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://192.168.1.100:8123/pic/2021-04-01/snap/939450165.jpg'
```

is there anything I can change?

Comment: open doesnt take a URL. it says `file is either a text or byte string giving the name (and the path if the file isn't in the current working directory) of the file to be opened`, if you want to fetch the data from a url use something like `requests` library

Comment: so I have to use `requests` to save the pictures on the computer first and then use `open` on the save path right?

Comment: requests wont save the picture to the computer, it will get the data and you can store it in memory. Just like open would get the data from a file and store it in memory. then you can do with the data anything like you would have done had you opened the data from a file